# Service implemented in feature component - error when returning observable table by httpclient

Tags: angular, observable, httpclient

Steps I want to include:
I want to fill and display the table  got from database, by using:
-service "DataService" with httpClient returning in method getPoints() Observable
-parent component "Data-import" with method implementTable() using  service method getPoints() from injected  DataService
-child component "Table-with_data" to which I bind by @Input property returned table Points[], model: Point{x,y}

(i have json-server)
* next problem would be get data from lastly uploaded csv file

+My problem appears between getPoints() method from servise and implementTable() in which i want to implement Points[]
+i don't know is there distinction between binding parent-child components values  "in normal type" vs "in observable type"

#### Data import component

```js
export class DataImportComponent implements OnInit {
  private points: Point[];
  private pointsObservable: Observable<Point[]>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  implementTable() {
    return this.dataService.getPoints().subscribe((data: Point[]) => {
      this.pointsObservable = data;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.implementTable();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <br />
  <app-table-with-data [point]="point" [points]="points"></app-table-with-data>
</div>
```

#### Data Service

```js
export class DataService {
  baseURL = "http://localhost:3000";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPoints(): Observable<Point[]> {
    return this.http.get<Point[]>(this.baseURL + "/points");
  }
}
```

#### Table component

```js
export class TableWithDataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() point: Point;
  @Input() points: Observable<Point[]>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let point of points | async">
    <td>{{ point.x }}</td>
    <td>{{ point.y }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My additional question is: how to make UploaderService injected in UploaderComponent work if i want to upload file and save it to the server becacuse the next thing i want to do is create this file in table form (table-with-data) which i explained above. Doest uploadFile and seveToServer methods are two separate actions or the second is part of the first? Here is my code:

```
export class UploaderService {

   baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

   constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}

   public uploadFile( file: File ): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post(this.baseURL+'uploaded', file );
   }


constructor( uploaderService: UploaderService ) { }

   public uploadFile( file: File ) {
        this.uploaderService.uploadFile(file);

   }

  public postOnServer(file: File){
        this.uploaderService.uploadFile(file);
    }

<input
  #fileInput
  type="file"
  class="upload__input"
  (change)="uploadFile( fileInput.file) ; fileInput.value = null;"
/>
<button (click)="postOnServer(fileInput.file)">Save file</button>
```

I tried to to this by example by it got me confused.

Comment: What is an error?

Comment: what's the purpose of `pointsObservable` in `DataImportComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue must be that you're passing down `Point[]` but the table component expects a `Observable<Point[]>`.

So you could change your parent component as follows:

```js
export class DataImportComponent {
  public points$: Observable<Point[]>;

  constructor(private readonly dataService: DataService) {
    this.points$ = this.dataService.getPoints();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <br />
  <app-table-with-data [points]="points$ | async"></app-table-with-data>
</div>
```

Here you'll subscribe to `points$` observable at top component and pass down values to child components (making them dumb).

So table component could be:

```js
export class TableWithDataComponent {
  @Input() points: Point[];
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let point of points">
    <td>{{ point.x }}</td>
    <td>{{ point.y }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Can I ask one more question related to this topic?/*i edited my post and at the end of it desribed it */

Comment: @Weronika it's better if you ask this as a separate question. 

Comment: if its possible, please give me some hint here, bacause i have got the  limit of question(one per day) so i can't add the one and i really need some help

Comment: I don't know how to answer your other question, it's really better if you'd ask it separately.